# MPMoviePlayerController continuos playback

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using MPMoviePlayerController to play my remote video of size 1.5MB. 
Currently, i am starting playback when "loadState" become "MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK" so that playback will be continuous. But it is taking more than 20 seconds to started playing. Is there any way to achieve continuos playback with play started in few seconds less than 20 second. Please let me know, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by showing video controls in "MPMovieLoadStatePlayable" load state so that user can play with those controls, to play/pause and toggle between embedded and full screen, even though they will not get continuos playback in this load state. But user do not need to wait untill full video gets downloaded.

Comment: I would suggest you to use HTTP-Streaming instead of progressive download.

Comment: Oh! Ok Till, actually we are not doing anything manually. We are using the following statement for remote video to play. MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:urlVideoThumbnail]; Using which method, this apple framework class is downloading the video? Is it HTTP-Streaming or something else? Please let me know, Thank you.

Comment: No, that is not HTTP-Streaming if the file you are handling is actually a plain MP4 file. HTTP-Streaming is handled via m3u8-manifests. For more information, have a peek at http://developer.apple.com/resources/http-streaming/

Comment: Ok Till, Thank you so much, i will take a look in into it.